# Allocate a (fixed size) vector<vector<double>> for efficient access and add them?

Tags: c++, performance, vector

I am implementing an algorithm that uses rather large vector(vector(double)) types for storage; no elements will be added or removed after preallocation. I would like to make sure that element access is as fast as possible, also I need to add and scale several of them (elementwise). What is the best way to do this?

Here are relevant parts of my (naive) code, that I doubt is efficient:

```cpp
vector<vector<double>> z;
vector<vector<double>> mu;
vector<vector<double>> temp_NNZ;
..

for(int i = 0; i < init.valsA.size(); ++i){
    z.push_back({});
    mu.push_back({});
    temp_NNZ.push_back({});
    for(int j = 0; j < init.valsA[i].size(); ++j){
        z[i].push_back(0);
        mu[i].push_back(0);
        temp_NNZ[i].push_back(0);
    }
}
..

for(int i = 0; i < z.size(); ++i){
    for(int j = 0; j < z[i].size(); ++j){
        z[i][j] = temp_NNZ[i][j] - mu[i][j]/rho - z[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: If you _would like to make sure that element access is as fast as possible_, then don't use a vector of vectors. Instead, use a plain 1-D vector and optionally wrap it with some class with element accessor based on two (row + column) indexes. And, always `reserve` or `resize` your vector if you know the number of elements in advance (which seems to be your case).

Comment: If you are looking for efficiency, don't use a 2d vector.  Instead put the vector in a class and make it a 1d vector of size `num_rows * num_cols`.  Then provide a way to access it as if it was a 2d vector.

Comment: best way to do is it to wrap single `std::vector` in a class representing a matrix.

Comment: And, even better best way is to use some library that do this wrapping for you (such as eigen :).

Comment: @DanielLangr true, as far as this is not task for online task, like hackerrank or spoj.

Comment: Alternatively, if size is known already at *compile time*(!), you could use `std::array<std::array<double, Columns>, Rows>` instead. That would spare you mapping two-dimensions into single one.

Comment: @Aconcagua Just beware of stack overflow (if automatic).

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the quick answers! Actually not all the vector<double> have the same size, hence to use a big 1D plane vector I guess I would need another vector that stores the indices of where the beginning of vector i is stored.. in this case is there still any benefit to this approach?

Comment: @schajan *' stores the indices of where the beginning'* – wait a second, does that mean you have a *jagged* array (i. e. every single row can have a different length)? Because *then* first having to look up some index to access the right position in the 1D array might consume again the speed gain of the 1D array. You'd have to profile to be sure, though. If not, no need to store indices, offset is simply calculated as `desiredRow * rowSize + desired column` (row size is the number of columns, of course).

Comment: That's exactly right, my array is jagged. I'm actually trying to represent a sparse matrix with z[i] being the entries in the ith row.

Comment: If you are representing a sparse matrix, then you should give a look to how sparse matrices are usually represented. I would create a _spare matrix_ class and represent them in Compressed Sparse Row format. Chances are you got already a library that implements this. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_(CSR,_CRS_or_Yale_format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this : `vector::resize` will create all the elements, and value-initialize them (or copy-initialize them if you give it an initial value), and `vector::reserve` will let you allocate the amount of memory you need in advance without initializing it (which may be more efficient). In the first case, you'll have to copy the final value to the already existing elements (`z[i] = x`) whereas in the other you'll have to create the elements as you would do with your current code (`z.push_back(x)`).